# jQuery containment not working on chrome,safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, drag-and-drop, jsplumb

I added some drag-able object to my code, there is problem with containment.  In chrome, the objects can move to out side off the div o the containment not working

Here is my sample URL: [Circle Dagger](http://webxtreams.net/demoprofiles004/circledragger.html)

(this happens when you drag object to end of right side, then drag another object to right side it can move beyond the div)
help me please

Comment: you really should add a doctype, without one i don't think this will work in all browsers. It actually seems to work correctly for me in Chrome but not in Ie ( if i manually exit quirks mode. in quirks mode it doesn't work at all, not draggable )

Comment: now i added 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

still bad there

Comment: when you drag object to end of the right side, then drag another object end  the right side, you can drag this beyond the div

Comment: I noticed that the `svg` element you have in there overflows outside of the container as well. Is that expected? I don't see what that would have to do with the balls overflowing, but maybe its a clue?

Comment: svg used for adding line between balls :)(this lines generate with plumbjs framework), is there a solution for get this pain

Comment: I do what is happening, but i don't know why. when you drag an object to the container edge, the constraint is growing in width or height (based on which edge) exponentially.

Comment: remove the plumbjs functionality to confirm it isn't interfering

Comment: removed, now wring fine, bt i need lines ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `div.wraproundx`.

The plumb lines created by the jsPlumb plugin create svg elements that overflow past the bounds of the container. Apparently, there is an issue with Chrome and jQuery UI in this regard, so you must set `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: This worked for me too, although I am using pure jquery-ui without jsPlumb.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this as containment

```
[
    $('#id'+randID).offset().left, 
    $('#id'+randID).offset().top,
    $('#id'+randID).offset().left+616,
    $('#id'+randID).offset().top+50
]
```

instead of containment: $('#id') and adjust by replacing (616) and (50), it works fine on chrome and FF